# How to create an array of unnamed objects in yaml?

Tags: yaml

In yaml, how can I create a collection of objects without naming them?

```
servers:
  ip:
  port:
  login:
  password:
```

I want something like this:

```
servers:
  - server:
      ip:
      port:
      login:
      password:

  - server:
      ip:
      port:
      login:
      password:

  - server:
      ip:
      port:
      login:
      password:
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

YAML sequence sign (`-`) is just a delimiter, so it allows to enumerate unnamed objects:

```
servers:
  - ip:
    port:
    login:
    password:

  - ip:
    port:
    login:
    password:

  - ip:
    port:
    login:
    password:
```

You may also leave `-` at its own line, as it is shown in `Example 2.4` in [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html):

```
servers:
  -
    ip:
    port:
    login:
    password:
```

Comment: much appreciated